# Как работает обработка аннотаций в JUnit?

Tags: java, аннотации

Не понимаю, как фреймворки работают с аннотациями.

Например, `JUnit`.
В классе у метода пишем `@Test` и уже можно запускать проект. Причем, без `Main` метода.

Мне понятно, что есть какой-то обработчик на рефлексии в который инкапсулированна логика.
НО, как при старте приложения фреймворк регистрирует свой обработчик аннотаций? Как `JVM` понимает, что нужно его использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы запускаете тесты, то вы их не запускаете как обычное java приложение. Вы запускаете либо из IDE либо с помощью плагинов к maven или gradle.

Рассмотрим сначала IDE. Тут используется специальный test runner, т.е. приложение с методом `main` (которое поставляется вместе с IDE), которое используя сканирование classpath (если запуск идет для всего проекта), либо использует конкретный класс (если тесты запускаются для конкретного класса). test runner с помощью рефлексии ищет методы с аннотацией, создает экземпляры теста и запускает их. Это приложение использует [API junit](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Runner.html), который позволяет запускать тесты.

Запускается он, когда вы выбираете пункт меню в IDE запустить тесты. Вот как конфигурация запуска тестов выглядит в eclipse:
[image: eclipse test runnner]

При нажатии на `Run` IDE запустит test runner.

Аналогично работают плагины для maven и gradle, во время сборки они используют API junit для запуска test runner-ов.

Т.е JVM нечего не знает. Если реализованные классы test runner-ов, которые занимаются поиском, инстанциированием и запуском тестов.

Comment: Хорошо, но кто запускает этот самый test runner? Автоматически IDE при старте?

Comment: Добавил в ответ. IDE запускает, когда вы запускаете тесты из IDE.